# How to make all files in any folder in Windows sorted by date created?

Tags: windows, automation, find-and-replace, files-folders, file-organization

When I sort files in folders I normally do it by name or by date created.

My problem is that in Windows 7, 8, 10, 11, **date created** is not a native sort criteria and it has to specially be turned on for any folder.

How to make all files in any folder in Windows sorted by date created (fast and easy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to a folder in File Explorer
2. Set the columns, view, etc. exactly as you like them to be
3. Then on the View Ribbon (tab) click 'Options'
4. On the resulting dialog, on the 'View' tab, click 'Apply to folders'

[image: Folder Options screenshot]

5. Then click Apply and OK

Any folder that contains the same type of data (General, Documents, Music, Pictures, or Videos) should then have that view with those same columns

Comment: In Windows 11 I have to click the three dots (horizontally), then on "Options" then on "View, then on Apply to Folders. Thanks a lot.